# Opening a file from .netrw in a specified split

Tags: vim, netrw

*This is  the same question as [on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/364645/opening-a-file-from-netrw-in-a-specified-split), but I feel it has a better chance of being answered here, so ...*

In Vim, I have four splits - two by two - and in the upper left one netrw is open. Is there a way to open a file from netrw in the lower right split, lower left, etc.?

Comment: It is a shame this question was never answered.

Comment: @RobertKluin - Waiting, hoping ........ :)

Answer (score 15):

there're some hints here https://superuser.com/questions/377501/keep-cursor-in-netrw-window-when-browsing-files-in-vim

Put this in your .vimrc,

```
let g:netrw_preview = 1
```

to configure vertical preview splits, then when the cursor is over the desired file, type <kbd>p</kbd> to open a preview window. To close the window, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>.

The term used in vim for a window that's opened without the cursor moving to it is a "preview window". To find out more about this, see

```
:help netrw-preview
:help CTRL-W_z
```

or just

```
:help netrw
```

and browse the table of contents for other browsing commands and other netrw features.

Comment: Is there a way to always show the preview for the file under the cursor?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the `g:netrw_chgwin` variable to make netrw open the files in a specific window. See:

```
:h netrw-C
```

So to make the current window the target of netrw type this while you're in that window:

```
:let g:netrw_chgwin = winnr()
```

Another way is to launch netrw in the target window (`:E`), hit `C` to select it for editing and close netrw with `<c-o>`.

Answer (score 2):

To bring above answers together some inspirations: I use the following window configuration together with netrw (together with :let g:netrw_liststyle = 2):

```
    -------------------------------- ...
    Netrw-split: topleft spilt
    -------------------------------- ...
             |          |          |
    working  | working  | working  |
    window 1 | window 2 | window 3 | ...
             |          |          |
```

Thus I can go directly to Netrw-split from every other window. Then I put to my .vimrc:

```
    augroup netrw
        autocmd!
        autocmd WinLeave * if &ft !=# "netrw" | let g:netrw_chgwin = winnr() | endif
        autocmd filetype netrw call Netrw_mappings()
    augroup END
```

The WinLeave command sets the global g:netrw_chgwin variable to the window just left (except if we are in the netrw-window).  Thus netrw will open any file in the window from which I accessed it and due to the window layout I can access netrw from any other window.

The autocmd 'filetype' is used to also create a new file in the window from which I accessed netrw.  For this netrw's '%' command has to be overwritten:

```
    function! Netrw_mappings()
        noremap <buffer>% :call CreateInLastWindow()<cr>
    endfunction
```

With a function creating the new file in window g:netrw_chgwin:

```
    function! CreateInLastWindow()
        let l:filename = input("new file's name: ")
        let l:netrwdir = b:netrw_curdir
        execute g:netrw_chgwin . "wincmd w"
        execute 'edit ' . l:netrwdir.'/'.l:filename
    endfunction
```